# How to make \titlestyle not italic

Tags: fonts, titles, moderncv

How do I make the `\titlestyle` in a normal font rather than italic in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) `casual` style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Perhaps `\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}` will work?

Answer (score 5):

The macro you're looking to edit is `\titlefont`.  From the class code:

```
...
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}
...
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}}
...
```

So you can just give

```
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
```

in your preamble (supplying whichever switches you want) and you should be good to go.